# How DO I disable minimize, maximize button in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

'm trying to make an application for chrome and I have the manifest file background.js and then the window.html. I'm trying to disable/remove the maximize/minimize button where it says x on the top of the right hand side of the page but I'm doing it for a chrome application . How do I disable it so people cant change the size of it? Code is needed tried looking for code and myself but couldn't find anything. Would be amazing if you could I know stack overflow is see code and get better code but I don't know any code for this please help me I'm desperate! thanks!

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT!

Comment: Please read how to write a question or you would end up getting so many downvotes

Comment: WHY DO YOU HAVE TO TALK SO LOUD?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [ask] and [mcve] then edit your question.  As part of the edit, turn off your CAPS LOCK key!  If you ask a good question then we can help you!  IF YOU JUST SHOUT AT US WE WILL RUN AWAY!

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding what your asking, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser limitation - you can't do this. Malicious actions like these are disabled by browsers.

However, you *can* open a window without a toolbar or menubar:

```
window.open("mypage.html","mywindowname", "toolbar=no,menubar=no");
```

Check out [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for more information on `window.open`.